# How to check if two checkbox or more is currently checked or not when a button is pressed

Tags: android, android-intent, if-statement, android-checkbox

This is my code :

```
public class Diagnosaage1 extends Activity{

Button b;
CheckBox check01,check02;
String a;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diagnosaage1);

    check01 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check01);
    check02 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check02);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            if(check01.isChecked()){
                Intent l = new Intent(Diagnosaage1.this, Diare.class);
                startActivity(l);
            }
            else if(check01.isChecked() && check02.isChecked()){
                Intent l = new Intent(Diagnosaage1.this, Diagnosa.class);
                startActivity(l);

            }
          }
    });

}
```

If Button01 is clicked it will check if two checkbox or more is currently checked or not,if the checkbox is currently checked it will go to another activity.

Comment: what actual u want ? as per ur code if check01 alone checked it will start Diare activity if both check01 and check02 is checked it will start diagnosa activity. But it will not work if second alone check. Please post the question properly.

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of the tests to have the most precise first:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(check01.isChecked() && check02.isChecked()){
        Intent l = new Intent(Diagnosaage1.this, Diagnosa.class);
        startActivity(l);
    } else if (check01.isChecked()){
        Intent l = new Intent(Diagnosaage1.this, Diare.class);
        startActivity(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is your solution. Good luck, Boopathi.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what are you trying to ask,based on your code ,if you select one chekbox01 it will go some other activity,if you click both it will go some other activity,if you only click checkbox02 it will not go any activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(check01.isChecked() && check02.isChecked()){
            Intent l = new Intent(Diagnosaage1.this, Diagnosa.class);
            startActivity(l);
        }  else if (check01.isChecked()){
            Intent l = new Intent(Diagnosaage1.this, Diare.class);
            startActivity(l);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i don't know what are you trying to ask,based on your code ,if you select one chekbox01 it will go some other activity,if you click both it will go some other activity,if you only click checkbox02 it will not go any activity

Comment: Carefull! This will open 2 activities since you have no `else if` only two `if`s

Comment: @doorstuck good sense